# Schedule change the fc-today highlight according to a particular timezone

Tags: jquery, date, timezone, fullcalendar

In primefaces schedule component schedule.js file by default uses new Date() to display or highlight the current date in schedule.

I got some code to change the date view date to a particular date and show

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var myschedule = PF('myschedule').jq.children(":first");
        var toDate = new Date(2015,02,22);
        myschedule.fullCalendar( 'changeView', 'agendaDay' );
        myschedule.fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', toDate );
});
```

This works..but my requirement is  on load of the schedule in the month view  the date should be according to the selected timezone date and gets highlighted.
Can anyone please help me to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
    var date = ["2015-04-22"];    
    $('.fc-day').each(function () {
        var thisdate = $(this).attr('data-date');
        var td = $(this).closest('td');

        if ($.inArray($(this).attr('data-date'), date) !== -1) {
            td.addClass('fc-state-highlight');
        }
    })
```

CSS:- 
       .fc-state-highlight
        {
              background:red
        }

This works...

Answer (score 0):

It´s not necessary to use Jquery selector. You can modify a cell while it´s rendered using [dayRender callback](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/dayRender/)

DayRender Callback

> function( date, cell ) { }

From doc:

> This callback is called each time a cell needs to be freshly rendered.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to explicitly set "today" on FullCalendar is the following (was a bit hard to find in the docs, but at last I did manage to find it).

```
$('.calendar').fullCalendar({
    now: moment().tz('Asia/Hong_Kong')
});
```

(Obviously, you'll need the Moment Timezone package as well.)

Here is the FullCalendar doc denoting this option:
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/now